# Cinnamon uses software rendering mode on VirtualBox even with Guest Additions and 3D acceleration

Tags: virtualbox, centos, opengl

I've got a CentOS 7.6.1811 guest running on Windows 10 and VirtualBox 5.2.30 with 3D Acceleration enabled.

The Linux guest has VirtualBox Guest Additions of the same version installed.

I had to install specific versions of kernel-headers and kernel-devel for 3.10.0-957.5.1 because the default `yum install kernel-headers kernel-devel` was installing headers for a slightly different version and `vboxadd setup`complained about it.

Now, despite I have followed every possible step found in instructions and forums, Cinnamon 3.6.7 continues using software rendering mode with nothing but a line at glass.log reading:

`error t=... Cinnamon Software Rendering Mode Enabled`

And at .xsession-errors there are two lines:

```
openGL version 2.1 Mesa 18 detected (GL Cogl Driver)
MetaSyncRing disabled: couldn't find required GL extensions, or the minimum safe openGL version was
```

Cinnamon boots with LightDM.

The interesting fact is that in the same VirtualBox I have another guest running the same OS but with VirtualBox Guest Additions 5.2.18 and it works fine. These other VM was created before VirtualBox was upgraded from 5.2.18 to 5.2.30.

In the VM where hardware acceleration works inxi -Gxx reports:

```
Graphics:
  Card-1: InnoTek Systemberatung VirtualBox Graphics Adapter 
  driver: vboxvideo v: 5.2.18 r124319 bus ID: 00:02.0 chip ID: 80ee:beef 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.19.5 driver: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa 
  alternate: vboxvideo resolution: 1920x975~60Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: Chromium v: 2.1 Chromium 1.9
  direct render: Yes
```

havning Mesa 17.2.3 installed

And the one in which does not work reports

```
Graphics:
  Device-1: InnoTek Systemberatung VirtualBox Graphics Adapter 
  driver: vboxvideo v: 5.2.30 r130521 bus ID: 00:02.0 chip ID: 80ee:beef 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.1 driver: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa 
  alternate: vboxvideo resolution: 1920x975~60Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 6.0 256 bits) v: 2.1 Mesa 18.0.5 
  direct render: Yes
```

`ldd /usr/bin/glxinfo` also reports different libraries on both VMs.
In the one where 3D acceleration works libGL.so.1 is a symlink to /var/lib/VBoxGuestAdditions/lib/libGL.so.1 but in the one which does not work libGL.so.1 symlink points to libGL.so.1.7.0 which seems to me like a library installed by Mesa 18.

So, apparently, it all boils down to Virtualbox Guest Additions set up not changing the OpenGL renderer to its Chromium engine.

Comment: A quick fix would be to install VirtualBox Guest Additions [5.2.18](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.2.18/).

Comment: I already tried to install 5.2.18 instead of 5.2.30 in the guest. But didn't work despite there is an older VM with 5.2.18 where 3D acceleration works. No matter what Guest Additions I install in the new machine it keeps using software rendering.

Comment: Two questions: Did you uninstall the previous Guest Additions before installing 5.2.18? If you cannot analyze the difference between the two VMs, perhaps using the working VM as template and transplanting the other software to it will be another quick solution.

Comment: I tried several orders in the new VM: first the guest additions (5.2.18 and 5.2.30) then Mesa and Cinnamon. No Luck. Then reverse order: first Mesa and Cinnamon starting in software rendering mode and the Guest Additions. No effect. I think that Mesa 18 just can't use the Chromium OpenGL 2.1 engine of Virtualbox. Also tried to downgrade to Mesa 17, but when trying to recompile it from source it requires libraries that are no longer compatible with CentOS 7.6.

Comment: You may find a compiled version of Mesa 17 in [here](https://pkgs.org/download/mesa-libGLES). What about my suggestion of cloning the VM that works?

Comment: Thanks @harrymc I can only find compiled Mesa 18 in pkgs.org not Mesa 17. The former VM can be cloned and then 3D acceleration works. But it runs CentOS 7.5 and the purpose of the change is an upgrade to CentOS 7.6 Moreover, even recreating the former VM from Vagrant leaves 3D out of order. It seems that something has changed in yum repos so that a vagrant up does not create the same machine which already exists in Virtualbox.

Comment: Have you examined [VBox.log](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Sun%20Microsystems/1342727_1.html)?